# Identify multiple UITextField and the row index

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview, uitextfield

Here is my problem:

I have an array of model class(Let's say, 'addressModel' with fields address, street and city.). Now i have a custom cell with three UITextFields for the three fields in the model class. Once the user ends editin, i want to (validate &) add the data in the particular textfield to the respective model object. (Ex: user ended editing addressTextField, then addressModel.address = addressTextField.text).

How can we identify the textfield that the user selected and the indexPath.row? In my case i need to know both? Any help?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your view controller implements the `UITextFieldDelegate` protocol, you can receive the `textFieldDidEndEditing` method call.  In there, you can get the tag of the field that the user was just editing.  When creating your cells you can specify some kind of integer tag scheme so that you can reverse engineer what section, row, and specific field the user was actually editing at the time.  You could do something like:

```
textField.tag = (indexPath.section * 10000) + (indexPath.row * 100) + (textFieldIndex);
```

Assuming you don't have more than 100 textFields per row, or 100 rows per section, this particular scheme should work.

Comment: Hi Dan thanks for the quick reply. i had thought of this, but do we have any other way? In the above logic the first row (0th) will be 1,2 etc rite? (where 1 = tag of the first textfield and so on)

Comment: Sections and rows are 0-indexed, so long as you follow the same convention when creating them, and "decoding" the tag, it won't matter.

Answer (score 0):

You can validate data when user finishes editing I mean you can validate data in UITextField delegate method:

```
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField;
```

here no need to find out which textfield is edited since you will get that textfield.And if you want to identified which row then you can assign tag which is nothing but row, to textfield and on that basis you will come to know which row textfield is edited.

Answer (score 0):

set the separate tag of each text field .. and on didEndEditing: method use the following code....

```
  if(textField.teg == FIRST_TAG){
      // do your code
  }
  else if(textField.teg == SECOND_TAG){
         // do your code
 }...

 and soo on....
```

may this will help you...